# What is the equivalent of Dependency Graph in GitHub for Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

GitHub's [Dependency Graph](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/understanding-your-software-supply-chain/about-the-dependency-graph#supported-package-ecosystems) tracks dependencies of your code. Is there a similar product that works with Azure DevOps repositories?

It needs to support npm, pip and dotnet dependencies.